# If thumbs down the person has to give a reason for it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, voting

I am new to the forum and I got a thumbs down (minus) to [one of my questions](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/19815/254). It is a good idea if the person can give the reason for the thumbs down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it generally is a good idea: it can be helpful if they can and do leave a comment.

Voting is anonymous and it's impossible to require a user to do to that: we can only ask them to.

I edited your question to include the additional explanation which you posted in comments. I think the question is clearer now.

Comment: Thank you Chris W. -)